# How to map data to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, materialize

I have data returned from the backend now i am trying to map it to react component which is throwing an error `Cannot read property of null` what is correct way to print keys in the div or card , i have also attached the data

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './app.css';
import ReactImage from './react.png';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export default class JOB_DESC extends Component {
  state = { data: null };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/getUsername');
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({ data: data });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name != "AbortError") this.setState({ error: e.message });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const data = this.state.data;
    console.log("DATA", data);
    return (
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="menu"
              sx={{ mr: 2 }} >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              Job.com
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <p>`{data["User Account"]}`</p>
                <p>`{data["User Location"]}`</p>
                <p> `{data["Company Name"]}`</p>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}
```

data

```
{ ‘User Account': Admin’,
‘User Location': ': New York, NY',
 'Company Name': ': Millennium’ }
```

Comment: Do you see that `data` printed in the browser console?

Comment: `data` state value is originally null, so on mounting and initial render, it's trying to read those properties of null. You'll have to handle the fact that the data takes a little time to load since it's fetched asynchronously, so render a loading spinner or message until `data` is no longer null

Comment: @tromgy yes it is printing in the browser console

Comment: as Jayce444 said.  render() method happened before componentDidMount function. thats why you get the error. try {data&&<div>....}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like by the time your component gets rendered, data will still be null as you've set it to null. So attempting to index null will give you `Cannot read property of null`.

What you'd want to do is wrap your component with a condition to check if data exists by the time it renders.

```js
{ data && (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <p>`{data["User Account"]}`</p>
                <p>`{data["User Location"]}`</p>
                <p> `{data["Company Name"]}`</p>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
)}
```